# Что такое загруженность процессора?

Tags: linux, процессор, эвм

Процессор по факту всегда выполняет какие то операции, вот он переключается с одного процесса на другой, но как понять загрузка процессора 15%, 20%.

Comment: *`"Процессор по факту всегда выполняет какие то операции..."`* -- не обязательно. У некоторых процессоров есть команда временного останова (например, WFI (wait for interrupt) в ARM), которая остананавливает выборку команд процессором и переводит его в режим низкого энергопоребления.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Windows (где собственно эти проценты и есть) есть специальная задача Idle, которая включается планировщиком, когда другие задачи не выполняются. А если другие задачи активно используют процессор, то эта задача, как низкоприоритетная, не получает время. И потом просто смотрится, а сколько в процентах времени работала задача Idle. Вот и все.

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-idle-process-high-cpu-usage/c43f365a-dc9b-49c0-a8d7-7305d43408d9